# PowerShell -replace function

Tags: powershell, replace

I am trying to find and replace a strings in a file and then saving it to the original file in PowerShell.

I've tried doing

```
(Get-Content "C:\Users\anon\Desktop\test.txt") 
-replace 'apple', 'apple1'
-replace 'bear' , 'bear1' |
Out-File test1.txt
pause
```

However, I keep getting

```
-replace : The term '-replace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\Xing Chen\Desktop\test.ps1:2 char:1
+ -replace 'apple', 'apple1'
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-replace:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I've been able to use `"abcd".replace()` fine and according to the documentation `-replace` should work too.

Comment: If you put the `-replace` operator in a new line without escaping the line break PowerShell will interpret `(Get-Content "C:\Users\anon\Desktop\test.txt")` as a complete statement and `-replace 'apple', 'apple1'` as another statement (with a command it doesn't recognize. Put the `-replace` operations on the same line as `Get-Content` and the problem will disappear.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Propose this as an answer; it will solve the querent's issue.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I consider this a case of "simple typographic error" and voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in your code to represent the line continuations and the interpreter is not seeing the `-replace` operators as part of the same command.  You have two options to resolve this: escaping the newlines or putting the commands on the same line.

```
@(Get-Content "C:\Users\anon\Desktop\test.txt") -replace 'apple','apple1' -replace 'bear','bear1' |
    Out-File -FilePath test1.txt
Pause
```

OR

```
@(Get-Content "C:\Users\anon\Desktop\test.txt") `
-replace 'apple','apple1' `
-replace 'bear','bear1' |
    Out-File -FilePath test1.txt
Pause
```